# Writing derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation, chain-rule

Can somebody please check my working?
**The variable $y$ depends on $x$ and $x$ and $t$ are related by $x=e^t$**

**Show that $x\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}$**

$$x=e^t$$
$$dx=e^t dt$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=e^t=e^t\times1=e^t \times\frac{dy}{dy}$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}\times\frac{dy}{dx}=x\frac{dy}{dy}\times\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=x\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: You treat $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as a fraction... A mathematician can go crazy for this. :)

Comment: Yeah. Same. Dealing dy/dx as fractions can make maths go haywire.

Comment: @Ixion: There is no problem with treating the differentials as fractions. The notation was adopted as it allows to represent the chain rule very intuitively.

Comment: Your development is dubious. There is no connection between the last two lines.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think you're right, but formally a student like me may lose the real meaning of what he's doing

Comment: @Ixion: I don't see how. Actually, in modern notation $dx$ and $dy$ are differentials, and it is rigourous to treat them as factors. The equations $dy=f'(x)\,dx$ and $dy/dx=f'(x)$... are perfectly valid.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: actually, I really don't know what to say. I'm not a mathematician (yet). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your answer, I am not sure how to get from line (3) to line (4).

I would proceed using the Chain Rule:
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt}
$$
but you know how $x$ depends on $t$, can you find $dx/dt$ and plug in?

Comment: Well I wrote $=e^t*1=e^t*\frac{dy}{dy}$. Is it incorrect?

Comment: @FaiqRaees I don't understand your comment. $dy/dy = 1$ so $e^t = e^t \frac{dy}{dy}$, but how does this help anyone? You already have all you need in terms of $y$, you just want to compute $dx/dt$ in terms of $x$ itself, not in terms of $y$.

Comment: @FaiqRaees I get it -- you think $dy/dy$ is a fraction? This is certainly wrong then (although it does behave somewhat similarly, but you cannot apply standard fraction arithmetic rules to it).

Comment: And for line 3-4 I multiplied dy/dx on both sides. Is it incorrect?

Comment: Oh. I do understand it is just dy/dy is just change in y/ change in y, but I thought it could behave as fractions like for integrations when we are making a substitution we deal these derivatives as functions. Why is that correct over there?

Comment: @gt6989b Such methods are commonly taught to applied students and work perfectly well here. In the context of this question, differentials are fractions.

Comment: @Kaynex I wish people who teach such fantasy were disqualified from teaching until they confess and repent. No, **differentials are never fractions** and it is quite tricky to know when they do, and when they don't behave as ones. There is a numerous amount of places where such "techniques" will create a nightmare in your calculations.

Comment: @Kaynex you're right, but I can tell you my teacher would become crazy if I wrote something like that. Anyway I think Leibniz would agree with Faiq Reaees.

Comment: Btw I am a pre-university student so I haven't been taught calculus at a very high level. So maybe we were introduced these simplicities to make the comprehension of the topic easier.

Comment: You will find this very instructive then -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906241/when-not-to-treat-dy-dx-as-a-fraction-in-single-variable-calculus

Comment: And then there's "non-standard analysis" which uses the Leibniz notion of infinitesimals: [here](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html)

Comment: @Χpẘ yes, there is, but that falls **way out** of the level of appreciation of the OP

Answer (score 1):

You are given $$y=f(x),x=e^t.$$

Then

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f'(x)$$ and by the chain rule,

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=f'(x)e^t=f'(x)x,$$ hence the claim.